# How to center the profile picture on my Sharepoint list gallery view card?

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have a Sharepoint List in Gallery view with JSON-formatting.
I have only one issue is that my profile picture isn't aligned center!
Everything else is only not my profile picture.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/tile-formatting.schema.json",
  "height": "300",
  "width": "300",
  "hideSelection": true,
  "formatter": {
    "elmType": "div",
    "style": {
      "display": "flex",
      "align-items": "stretch",
      "margin-bottom": "16px",
      "min-width": "150px",
      "justify-content": "space-around",
      "padding": "5px"
    },
    "customRowAction": {
      "action": "defaultClick"
    },
    "children": [
      {
        "elmType": "div",
        "style": {
          "width": "95%",
          "height": "92%",
          "box-shadow": "0px 1.6px 3.6px 0 #00000024, 0px 0.3px 0.9px 0 #00000024",
          "overflow": "hidden",
          "border-radius": "2px",
          "padding-left": "16px",
          "padding-top": "16px"
        },
        "attributes": {
          "class": "ms-bgColor-neutralLighterAlt ms-bgColor-neutralLight--hover ms-fontColor-themePrimary--hover"
        },
        "children": [
          {
            "elmType": "div",
            "style": {
              "text-align": "center"
            },
            "children": [
              {
                "elmType": "div",
                "children": [
                  {
                    "elmType": "img",
                    "style": {
                      "display": "block",
                      "border-radius": "50%",
                      "margin-bottom": "25px",
                      "text-align": "center"
                    },
                    "attributes": {
                      "src": "=getUserImage([$FotoE.email], 'M')"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "elmType": "div",
                "style": {
                  "text-align": "center"
                },
                "children": [
                  {
                    "elmType": "div",
                    "style": {
                      "color": "#333333",
                      "font-size": "16px",
                      "font-weight": "600"
                    },
                    "txtContent": "[$field_1]"
                  },
ETC..
```

Gr. P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please do not set img to block or set img to inline-block.
[image]
[image]